# Prove for all integers $x$ and $y$: $x y = x$ → $y = 1$ using field axioms.

Tags: ring-theory, axioms

Knowing for all integers $x$ and $y$: $x y = x$, prove $y = 1$ using only the following axioms:
Associativity of addition.
Existence of additive identity.
Existence of additive inverses.
Commutativity of multiplication.
Associativity of multiplication.
Existence of multiplicative identity.
Distributive law.

Note that there's no multiplication inverse, is this proof still possible?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid the use of * to denote multiplication. It's a common practice in programming languages but not in Mathematics.

Comment: The title of the question mentions the field axioms, but the body says there's no multiplicative inverse, and you've used the ring-theory tag. Did you mean to say ring axioms in the title?

Comment: I'm new to this topic, I just mean using field axioms.

Comment: @fleablood is the proof impossible without multiplication inverse?

Comment: Yes.... a prove without the existence of the multiplicative inverse *is* possible.  Hint:  Let $x = 1$ then  .........

Comment: The lack of the multiplicative inverse axiom means that it is possible for $y \cdot x = x$ for *some* $x$ without $y = 1$ but  in order for $y \cdot x = x$ for *all* $x$ we must have $y = y\cdot 1 = 1$.  If we have the multiplicative inverse axiom we can prove that if $y \cdot x = x$ for *any* $x\ne 0$ we must have $y = 1$.  But *without* the inverse axiom we could have $y \cdot x=x;y \ne 1$ for *some* $x \ne 0, 1$ without a contradiction.

Comment: FWIW  I was mistaken when I said the lack of the inverse axiom was probably an accidental omission.  I think now it was a *deliberate* omission as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @fleablood Could you explain a little more on why letting x=1 can prove y=1? I still think x=1 only proves one case of x. I'm still struggling after one day trying to prove this. "If y≠1 the we would have y=y⋅1=1≠y and that is a contradiction." Why does y * 1 = 1 if x≠1?

Comment: You aren't trying to prove *anything* about *any* values of $x$.  You are *TOLD*  (by GOD ON HIGH) that for *EVERY* value of $x$ that $yx = x$.  That is a GIVEN.  What you need to prove is that that means $y = 1$.....  Now you are told that $yx=x$ for **EVERY** *possible* value of $x$ that $yx = x$ that means it must be true for the one case where $x=1$.  So it **MUST** be true that $y\cdot 1 = 1$.  You were *TOLD* that.   ..... Okay.... so you know that $y\cdot 1 = 1$.   But $1$ is the identity so $y\cdot 1= y$.  ANd by transitivity of equality that means $y = y\cdot 1 = 1$.

Comment: Okay...... Forget $x$..... who cares about $x$..... Here is the question:   What is $y\cdot 1$?   Argument 1:   As $y\cdot x = x$ for all $x$ we must have $y\cdot 1 = 1$.  That is a given property of $y$.   Argument 2:  As $1$ is the identity we must have $y\cdot 1 = y$.  That is a given property of $y$.  So which argument is correct?  They both are!  So we must have that $y\cdot 1 = 1$  *AND* $y\cdot 1 = y$.  But how can that be?  $y\cdot 1$ can only be one thing! The only way $y\cdot 1$ can be both is if they are both the *same* thing.  So we have to have $y, y\cdot 1$ and $1$ are all .....

Comment: Oh.... a day late and a dollar short..... If $x,y$ are *INTEGERS* with multiplication and addition $\mathbb Z$ is *NOT* a field and you do *not* have the field axioms.  So lack of multiplicative inverse was *not* an omission.  $\mathbb Z$ is not a field ant integers do not *have* multiplicative inverses (as integers). ... (The integers form a *ring with unity* [that is a ring with a multiplicative identity].... They have all the axioms of a field *except* the elements need not have multiplicative inverses.)

Comment: @fleablood, Sorry, I think I phrased the question wrong and caused misunderstanding. I just edited the question, could you take a look and see if the solution still works?

Comment: Nothing's changed. You are being ask to prove if Statement 1: $y$ is an integer so that for any integer $x$ that $yx = x$ then Statement 2:  $y = 1$.  If statement 1 is true then $y=y\cdot 1 = 1$ so statement 2 is true.   So Statement 1$\implies$ Statement 2.

Comment: Actaully what you have written now makes no sense.  "Knowing for all integers x and y: xy=x"  Well, that is just plain false.  For example if if $x = 17$ and $y = 38$ then $17\cdot 38\ne 17$ so that's just plain false.  If we know that $xy =x$ for all integers $x,y$ we *can* prove that $y=1$ but we can also prove $y=\sqrt \pi$ and Elephants eat puffed crocodiles for a tea snack.... Why don't you write *exactly* what the question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 1 \implies 1\cdot y = 1 \implies y = 1$

Comment: Is it possible to prove it for all integer x?

Comment: You don't have to prove for all $x$....   You are given that $y\cdot x = x$ for all $x$.  That means that for $x = 1$ we *must* have $y \cdot 1 = 1$.  But by definition of $1$ we have $y\cdot 1 = y$ so........ $y = y\cdot 1 =  1$.  And that's it.  $y=1$ is the only way we can have $yx = x$ for all $x$.... If $y \ne 1$ the we would have $y = y\cdot 1 = 1 \ne y$ and that is a contradiction.